# jQuery for timeline with expand and collaps function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have to `create patient Timeline` as par 
[link for demo](http://pjd.mscui.net/PrimaryCare.htm)

on this link please visit on timeline menu as per describe below

[image: visit Timeline link]

Here i want to display patient visits for hospital according to visit date.also scrollbar according to year as you can see on link provided above.

i found many jquery but no one best as par my requirement.
I request you people to please help me to find out any jquery or anything related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got `query` as per my requirement form below link...

[Example link](http://www.technotarek.com/timeliner/timeliner.html)

thanks to all who tried to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: from above link i can fin collapse/Expand but i also want scroll group by year like(2001,2002..etc) and according to that want to display data on div according to that year..